# Select a tag inside a class with bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the href of this part of html:

```
<h3 class="post-title entry-title" itemprop="name">
<a href="http://sslproxies24.blogspot.it/2016/10/01-10-16-free-ssl-proxies-1070.html">01-10-16 | Free SSL Proxies (1070)</a>
</h3>
```

So I created this script:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://sslproxies24.blogspot.it/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
for tag in soup.find_all("h3", "post-title entry-title"):
    links = tag.get("href")
```

But links, doesn't find anything. This is because, the class "post-title entry-title" that I selected with bs4, has not attribute "href"...

In fact the output of:

```
print (tag.attrs)
```

is:

```
{'itemprop': 'name', 'class': ['post-title', 'entry-title']}
```

How can I do to select the "a" element and get the links in href?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can quickly solve it by getting the inner `a` element:

```
for tag in soup.find_all("h3", "post-title entry-title"):
    link = tag.a.get("href")
```

where `tag.a` is a shortcut to `tag.find("a")`.

Or, you can match the `a` element directly with a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for a in soup.select("h3.post-title.entry-title > a"):
    link = a.get("href")
```

where dot is a *class* attribute selector, `>` means *direct parent-child relationship*.

Or, you can check `itemprop` attribute instead of a class:

```
for a in soup.select("h3[itemprop=name] > a"):
    link = a.get("href")
```